WebRTC works locally, fails when deployed
I developed a Next.js website and an iPhone app that connect via WebRTC. The iPhone app streams video that can be viewed on the website. The website functions well locally, but after deploying it to Vercel or Netlify, the video stream becomes very slow and eventually fails completely.
I only use the Next.js /api folder for NextAuth, so I assume there shouldn't be any difference whether the website runs locally or is deployed.
For ICE servers, I use STUN/TURN servers provided by Twilio. I've tested running the website locally in both development and production builds, and it works fine. Therefore, I don't think the issue lies with the build itself.
The only clue I've found is that locally, the network-cost for ICE candidates does not exceed 50, whereas in deployment, it reaches 999.
As far as I understand, once the deployed website is downloaded to the client, the WebRTC connection is established peer-to-peer. Therefore, there shouldn't be a difference between running it locally and running it in deployment. I'm unsure how to debug and resolve this problem.
